# Windows Phone 8.1 Edit Template Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Can someone help me to fix visual studio 2015 RC Enterpise/Blend exception or can explain why this error appear?

1) Right click on CheckBox: [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7t8z.png)

2) Select element: Edit Template -> Edit a Copy

3) Select settings:

3.1) Key: NewCheckBoxTemplate

3.2) Define in: App.xaml or in other place

4) Error: [Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeWoH.png)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess it's just a bug. Wait for the RTM, it's probably going to get fixed until then.

Comment: Not sure exactly without more details, but try a solution search for `targettype="checkbox"` and just find the resource dictionary it sits in as a workaround, then you can copy it from there.